# Minimum hardware requirements for gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

How can I determine what is the minimum hardware requirement for install the **gitlab-runner** on a host? 
I want a specific runner which will run tests, build docker images, and deploy the apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/requirements.html#gitlab-runner) gives some advices and put focus on memory :

> Depending on how you decide to configure GitLab Runner and what tools you use to exercise your application in the CI environment, GitLab Runner can consume significant amount of available memory.

After that, it's really depending the type of application you want to test/build/deploy. Test and build job will be the largest resource consumers. You can also set [limits](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) on cpu/memory for docker runner.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But what is your solution (if you use gitlab-runner) to this problem? In other words where are your runners (for example, in a dedicate VM only for runners or alongside the other apps in a server?

Comment: Like I said, it depends of what you test/build/deploy. I use gitlab-runner on aws and I do docker-in-docker to test/build/deploy mainly nodejs application. For each job, my runner spin off an EC2 m4.large (2vCPU, 8Go RAM) spot instance temporary for the time of the job.